# How can I return a QList<specificObject*> pointer and get no memory leak?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, pointers, qlist

I have a question and a answer table in my database. The relation between those two is that a question can have multiple answers. In my C++ code I have A Question plain object, which stores the question text and a QList of answers. The Answer plain object just stores the answer text.

I want to read all questions and all answers related to these questions and store them in my question object. this is what I did.

```
QList<Question*> *ExamPersistance::readQuestions(int examId)
{
    QList<Question*> *questions;
    QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(connection->getDb());
    query->prepare("select q.id, q.text from question q where id_exam =:examId");
    query->bindValue(":examId",examId);
    query->exec();
    while(query->next())
    {
        questions->append(new Question(
                             query->value(1).toString(),
                                       this->readAnswers(query->value(0).toInt())));
    }
    return questions;
}

QList<Answer*> *ExamPersistance::readAnswers(int questionId)
{
    QList<Answer*> *answers;
    QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(connection->getDb());
    query->prepare("select a.text from answer a where id_question = :questionId");
    query->bindValue(":questionId",questionId);
    query->exec();
    while(query->next())
    {
        answers->append(new Answer(query->value(0).toString()));
    }
    return answers;
}
```

I am getting segmentation fault and I don't know why.

These are my constructors in my header files

```
 Answer(QString text);
 Question(QString name, QList<Answer*> *answers);
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong with the pointers. I have to admit I am not very familiar with these as I came from Java.

EDIT:

I have also a class "exam" which stores questions to a certain exam but I didn't consider this important to mention. Just that you know what this "int examId" stands for

Comment: Segfault != Memory leak

Comment: Are you using the same database connection to run the two queries concurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I return a QList pointer and get no memory
>   leak?

The easiest and likely the optimal way would be to store values and not pointers:

```
QList<Question> listOfQuestions;
QList<Answer> listOfAnswers;
```

Also, we can make the collection of shared pointers. But that is not an intended use of those so read on QSharedPointer.

```
QList<QSharedPointer<Question>> listOfQuestions;
QList<QSharedPointer<Answer>> listOfAnswers;
```

Otherwise you need to figure out what object is responsible for releasing the object you pass to list as pointer (very popular Qt techniques by providing the 'parent' pointer).

List of values in practice:

```
QList<Question> ExamPersistance::readQuestions(int examId)
{
    QList<Question> questions;
    QSqlQuery query(connection->getDb());
    query.prepare("select q.id, q.text from question q where id_exam =:examId");
    query.bindValue(":examId",examId);
    query.exec();
    while(query.next())
    {
        questions.append(Question(
                             query.value(1).toString(),
                                       this->readAnswers(query.value(0).toInt())));
    }
    return questions;

}

QList<Answer> ExamPersistance::readAnswers(int questionId)
{
    QList<Answer> answers;
    QSqlQuery query(connection->getDb());
    query.prepare("select a.text from answer a where id_question = :questionId");
    query.bindValue(":questionId",questionId);
    query.exec();
    while(query.next())
    {
        answers.append(Answer(query.value(0).toString()));
    }
    return answers;
}
```

Of course mind the actual constructor parameters which is not seen from your question. With C++ 11 and 'move' constructors in use that should be very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to initialize some pointers.

Version with crash and memleak fixed:

```
QList<std::unique_ptr<Question>> ExamPersistance::readQuestions(int examId)
{
    QList<std::unique_ptr<Question>> questions;
    QSqlQuery query(connection->getDb());
    query.prepare("select q.id, q.text from question q where id_exam =:examId");
    query.bindValue(":examId",examId);
    query.exec();
    while(query.next())
    {
        questions.append(std::make_unique<Question>(
                             query.value(1).toString(),
                                       this->readAnswers(query.value(0).toInt())));
    }
    return questions;
}
```

Comment: I would say that is possible but a bit beyond Qt and such list of unique pointers is a bit not what C++ standard creators preaching for.

Comment: @AlexanderVX: Not sure if by value is correct for OP case, but I agree than `QList<Question>` would be better if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing the QList pointers but you never initialized them (ie they are pointing at garbage). This code should solve that problem.

```
QList<Question*> *ExamPersistance::readQuestions(int examId)
{
    QList<Question*> *questions = new QList<Question*>();
    QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(connection->getDb());
    query->prepare("select q.id, q.text from question q where id_exam =:examId");
    query->bindValue(":examId",examId);
    query->exec();
    while(query->next())
    {
        questions->append(new Question(
                             query->value(1).toString(),
                                       this->readAnswers(query->value(0).toInt())));
        }
        return questions;

    }

QList<Answer*> *ExamPersistance::readAnswers(int questionId)
{
    QList<Answer*> *answers = new QList<Answer*>();
    QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(connection->getDb());
    query->prepare("select a.text from answer a where id_question = :questionId");
    query->bindValue(":questionId",questionId);
    query->exec();
    while(query->next())
    {
        answers->append(new Answer(query->value(0).toString()));
    }
   return answers;

}
```

Note that this is just the issue I found. Even if this code runs, there are other problems with it. You are definitely leaking the memory associated with the variable query and may be leaking memory to all of the Questions and Answer objects (and the QLists while we're at it) unless you delete them some point later on down the road. In C++ you need to call delete for every call to new or you are leaking memory. It is generally frowned upon in C++ to use pointers unless you actually need to. This differs substantially from Java where you have to use new to create an object. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014747/diffrence-between-new-operator-in-c-and-new-operator-in-java) has a decent discussion on the differences of the new operator in C++ and Java and is a good starting point.

Comment: You're making it worse by creating the QList itself on the heap, too (for which there is almost never a good reason)

Comment: @Frank in general I try to change provided code as minimally as possible to provide a working sample. Since I read the question as actually being "why does this segfault" not really "why are there mem leaks" I fixed the segfault, but yes nothing should be on the heap in this case and AlexanderVX provides an example of this in another answer

Comment: Ah, sorry, right, his example has the pointers. I was probably accidentally looking at another answer.